# Run crontab only if condition

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script that emails me whenever a web server is not responding, and the script is ran by `cron` every 5 minutes. However, if the website goes down for a few hours, I'd receive too many messages instead of just one.

What's the best way to make it email only once? Should I use an environment variable and check it before sending the email/resetting it when web server goes up again? Are there better ways to do this (without polluting the environment)? Am I doing something silly right now? I'm not confident in my shell scripting skills.

```
#!/bin/sh

output=$(wget http://lon2315:8081 2>&1)
pattern="connected"

if [[ ! "$output" =~ "$pattern" ]]
then
    echo "$output" | mail -s "Website is down" "myemail@asdf.com"   
fi
```

Comment: I don't think you can use environment variables, as they won't persist between script "runs". What about writing to a temporary file in `/tmp`, then checking it each time?

Comment: @Sparhawk thanks, that sounds like a good idea. However, I see that the uptime for the machine I'm working on is 49 days, yet the oldest file in `/tmp/` is 10 days, so I'm thinking they might use other methods for cleaning /tmp/ other than reboot. I guess writing on a file on my own dir should work

Comment: Yes, probably a good idea, especially if it's a shared system, and you can't be sure of the contents of `/tmp`.

Comment: Done, and thanks. I added some code too so I felt like I deserved some rep. :) Let me know if you need help understanding any of it.

Comment: As the script is an elementary state machine, I'd rather use `/var/tmp`, `/var/cache` or `/run` for caching state variables. `/tmp` is really a pot for everything and anything.

Comment: `monit` can check websites through ping or HTTP access and be customized to issue alerts intelligently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can use environment variables, as they won't persist between script "runs".

Alternatively, you could write to a temporary file in `/tmp` or somewhere in your home directory, then check it each time?

For example, something like

```
#!/bin/sh

output=$(wget http://lon2315:8081 2>&1)
pattern="connected"
tempfile='/tmp/my_website_is_down'

if [[ ! "$output" =~ "$pattern" ]]
then
    if ! [[ -f "$tempfile" ]]; then
        echo "$output" | mail -s "Website is down" "myemail@asdf.com"
        touch "$tempfile"
    fi
else
    [[ -f "$tempfile" ]] && rm "$tempfile"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit dirty, but I would put a file in `/tmp` or some other place which gets removed when the server is back up again.

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

output=$(wget http://lon2315:8081 2>&1)
pattern="connected"
websitedownfile="/tmp/websitedown"

if [[ ! "$output" =~ "$pattern" ]]; then

    if [[ -e $websitedownfile ]]; then
        echo "$output" | mail -s "Website is down" "myemail@asdf.com"
    fi
    touch $websitedownfile
else
    [[ -f $websitedownfile ]] && rm $websitedownfile
fi
```